# Laravel dockerized app taking DB_HOST as SERVER_ADDR instead of container

Tags: mysql, laravel, docker, docker-compose

I have a laravel app and the database containers are configured in this way:

```
db:
  image: "mysql:5.7"
  command: ["--sql- mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"]
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: mydb
    MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD: 'yes'
  volumes:
   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
    - simple_net

app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./setup/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
    environment: 
      DB_CONNECTION: mysql
      DB_HOST: db
      DB_DATABASE: mydb
      DB_USERNAME: root
     # SERVER_ADDR: localhost
```

When I tried to start the app with docker-compose up it throws an exception that says `SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root'@'172.23.0.6' (using password: NO).`  The IP refers to the environmental variable SERVER_ADDR, I tried to set it up with the values  localhost and '' (empty) but  nothing has worked so far.

Answer (score 1):

You should set the .env's `DB_HOST` to the name of your container, in your case `db`.

`DB_HOST=db`

I do not believe injecting environment variables replaces filling the .env.

Also, if you want to Dockerize your Laravel applications, several options already exist and work out of the box:

- [Laradock](https://github.com/laradock/laradock)
- [Docker Compose Laravel](https://github.com/aschmelyun/docker-compose-laravel)
- [Laradose](https://github.com/AdrienPoupa/laradose) (which I maintain)

Comment: didn't work. Still persisiting the connection from the IP being refused

Comment: Can you connect to your database from your host?

Comment: no, Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Comment: Then your issue is not with Laravel but your database container. Maybe try using a password, or see how the packages I linked above do it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need       `DB_CONNECTION: mysql` there.

Instead inside your .env file in lavel  you will use this like:

```
  DB_CONNECTION: mysql
  DB_HOST: db
  DB_PORT: 3306
  DB_DATABASE: mydb
  DB_USERNAME: root
  DB_PASSWORD: password
```

Your `app` container does not need this environment, that's your server running. You try to configure the environment of the db container inside server container which will run your app.

Change your docker-compose to:

```
db:
  image: "mysql:5.7"
  command: ["--sql- mode=STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_ZERO_IN_DATE,NO_ZERO_DATE,ERROR_FOR_DIVISION_BY_ZERO,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"]
  environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_USER: root
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATBASE: mydb
      MYSQL_USER: root
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: password
      SERVICE_TAGS: dev
      SERVICE_NAME: mysql
  volumes:
   - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
  restart: unless-stopped
  networks:
    - simple_net

app:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: ./setup/Dockerfile
    restart: unless-stopped
    tty: true
    ports:
      - "${APP_PORT}:80"
    working_dir: /var/www/
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/
    networks:
      - simple_net
```

Bridge your containers under your network so they can interact with each other.

Run `docker-compose up --build` and then access your laravel container and run inside the container `php artisan optimize` to configure cache for routes,env variables, files etc etc.

```
docker exec -it db mysql -u root -p password
```

Based on your comments you have issues to access the container and the reason is you don't use credentials for it and mysql tries to use the default ones. Above command defines the right user and password, you will also be asked to fill the password.

Also mysql has more parameters to define the host etc etc you can have a look further for that.

Comment: Didn't work. When I tried docker-compose exec db mysql  I got this error. Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO). I tried deleting and pulling the image again

Comment: Did you try the docker command i send you? That will rebuild all your containers. The command you are trying is the one to access the db container and you are doing it wrong. When you try to connect to mysql from command line you must send the username, pass etc etc as parameters. So your error is expected since you are simply trying to access mysql without sending the correct parameters and mysql uses the default ones.

Comment: I tried docker-compose build --no-cache. I even removed all the volumes, deleted mysql:5.7 image and pulled it back again. I even tried with mariadb. I tried adding the environmental variable MYSQL_ROOT_HOST: '%' and nothing worked

Comment: Are your containers up and running? run docker ps and check your containers if they are actually up. It's not an image problem, mysql command requires parameters and you are not giving any that's why mysql uses the default credentials which are not right so it fails with invalid

Comment: I stopped all my containers and even run docker-compose -v, docker-compose build --no-cache, follow by docker-compose up

Comment: @BlueSoul how much reputation is required to Approve or reject suggested edits?.